# Can't resolve "c is not a constructor" error

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I'm trying to build a very very basic "proof of concept" app using ExtJS but i'm having a very hard time.

All i want is two grids getting their data from a remote JSON file, but no matter what i do i keep on getting the error that's in the subject.

Here is my simple code:

**app.js:**

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});

Ext.application({
    name: 'GeoSniffer',
    autoCreateViewport: true,
    models: ['Location', 'Client'],    
    stores: ['Locations', 'Clients'],
});
```

**Viewport.js**

```
Ext.define('GeoSniffer.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    layout: 'fit',

    requires: [
        'GeoSniffer.view.ClientsList',
        'GeoSniffer.view.LocationsList'
    ],

    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = {
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [{
                width: 250,
                xtype: 'panel',
                id: 'west-region',
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'locationslist',
                    flex: 1
                },{
                    xtype: 'clientslist',
                    flex: 1             
                }]
            }]
        };

        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

**Client.js:**

```
Ext.define('GeoSniffer.model.client', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'ip', 
        'packetsCount', 
        'firstPacketUsec', 
        'latestPacketUsec', 
        'location', 
        'sessionsArr', 
        'currentSession'
    ]
});
```

**Location.js:**

```
Ext.define('GeoSniffer.model.Location', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'countryCode', 
        'countryName', 
        'region', 
        'city', 
        'postalCode', 
        'latitude', 
        'longitude', 
        'dma_code', 
        'area_code', 
        'metro_code', 
        'packetsCount', 
        'sessionsArr', 
        'currentSession', 
        'clients'
    ]
});
```

**Clients.js:**

```
Ext.define('GeoSniffer.store.Clients', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: 'GeoSniffer.model.Client',
    model: 'GeoSniffer.model.Client',
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data/clients.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'clients_list'
        }
    }
});
```

**Locations.js:**

```
Ext.define('GeoSniffer.store.Locations', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: 'GeoSniffer.model.Location',
    model: 'GeoSniffer.model.Location',
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data/locations.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'locations_list'
        }
    }
});
```

**ClientsList.js:**

```
Ext.define('GeoSbiffer.view.ClientsList', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.clientslist',

    store: 'Clients',
    title: 'Clients',
    hideHeaders: true,

    initComponent: function() {
        this.columns = [
            {
                dataIndex: 'ip',
            },
            {
                dataIndex: 'packetsCount',          
            }

        ];

        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

**LocationsList.js:**

```
Ext.define('GeoSbiffer.view.LocationsList', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.locationslist',

    store: 'Locations',
    title: 'Locations',
    hideHeaders: true,

    initComponent: function() {
        this.columns = [{
            dataIndex: 'countryName',
            flex: 1
            },{
            dataIndex: 'city',
            flex: 1             
            }

        ];

        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

**clients.json**

```
{
    "sessions_arr": [ 7, 0, 6, 1, 6, 8, 2, 39, 0, 5, 12, 8],
    "clients_list": [
      {
        "ip": "82.166.201.153",
        "packetsCount": 1,
        "firstPacketUsec": 211474,
        "latestPacketUsec": 211474,
        "location": {
          "countryCode": "IL",
          "countryName": "Israel",
          "region": "unknown",
          "city": "unknown",
          "latitude": 31.5,
          "longitude": 34.75,
          "dma_code": 0,
          "area_code": 0,
          "metro_code": 0,
          "packetsCount": 0,
          "currentSession": 0,
          "clients": []
        },
        "sessionsArr": [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        "currentSession": 1
      }
    ],
    "status": {
      "executionResult": "OK",
      "isSnifferActive": false,
      "servletInfo": ""
    }
}
```

**locations.json**

```
{
    "sessions_arr": [ 7, 0, 6, 1, 6, 8, 2, 39, 0, 5, 12, 8],
    "locations_list": [
      {
        "countryCode": "US",
        "countryName": "United States",
        "region": "CA",
        "city": "Palo Alto",
        "postalCode": "94304",
        "latitude": 37.376205,
        "longitude": -122.1826,
        "dma_code": 807,
        "area_code": 650,
        "metro_code": 807,
        "packetsCount": 2,
        "sessionsArr": [ 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        "currentSession": 0,
        "clients": [
          {
            "ip": "69.171.242.14",
            "packetsCount": 2,
            "firstPacketUsec": 368942,
            "latestPacketUsec": 369060,
            "sessionsArr": [ 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            "currentSession": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "status": {
      "executionResult": "OK",
      "isSnifferActive": false,
      "servletInfo": ""
    }
}
```

trying to debug with Firebug through the stack trace gave no helpful info.

What am i missing??

---

The place the code fails:

[image: Call stack and breakpoint place]

Comment: Can you break on the error, then follow the stack trace to see where `c` came from?

Comment: @JamesClark: I added to my question a screen shot of the call stack and the break line...

Comment: It is attempting to instantiate an Ext class.  I think the answer will be in the `alias` method, two entries down the stack trace.  It will probably be trying to resolve some xtype there, and that will help the next step in the diagnosis.

Answer (score 18):

When using the loader, make sure you are running with `ext-all-dev.js` (or `ext-dev.js`) *not* `-debug`. `-dev` will report loader errors, but `-debug` will not. This type of problem is a pain to track down as the application grows, but dev will report it right away (in your console).

I have only seen this tidbit mentioned once, but it has saved me days of debugging.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much! Finally I know what the dev file is for. Nobody tells you that. Best hint for tracking down such errors...

Comment: I will not avoid this comment, definitely +1! It's important to know this difference, it saves a lot of time of debug!

Comment: @david-kanarek ah, I downloaded ExtJS 5, I got ext-all, ext-debug ext-rtl but not ext-dev ! ? any idea about this new version ?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used EXT in a while now. I'd try using all the various versions and see if any report the error in the console. You might also check Sencha's docs to see if they've done anything to make this problem easier to find.

Answer (score 1):

I reporoduced this error and I've found out that `GeoSniffer.store.Clients` because you've got typo in your `client.js` file. There is `GeoSniffer.model.client` instead of `GeoSniffer.model.Client`. There is also `GeoSbiffer` namespace used in *List files.

Comment: Guess he "biffed" it