# ExtJS 4: "c is not a constructor"

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I'm using chrome to develop an ExtJS application.
Today I tried to open my app in Firefox 10.0.2 and it doesn't even start up.

I keep getting this Error Message:

```
c is not a constructor | ext-debug.js (Line 6662)
```

I'm not sure where to start to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That happens when a file that it needs is missing. It's a very generic message, check you have all the files needed via .Requires in your code.

It's caught me out before where I had the right files, but they weren't loading in the order they were being called.

Comment: I had a similar thing, it would work in Chrome, but not Firefox, as it was loading the files in a different order. Not sure why though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453516/cant-resolve-c-is-not-a-constructor-error, ext-dev will show the correct message.